# Updating text in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to update a text variable every time a player makes a move. The problem is that every time I do so, the new string appears on top of the previous string. When I resize or expand the game window, the string is displayed normally.

PROBLEM STATE:

[image: PROBLEM STATE]

EXPANDED STATE (DESIRED STATE):

[image: EXPANDED STATE (DESIRED STATE)]

Below I provide the code of where the problem is. I know my code may not be the best, but I just started to learn sfml, so sometimes I hardcode a little bit to get quick results. As soon as I finish this, I will rewrite the whole application with better programming practices. The places where the said string is handled are in void handle_plmove_request(game_packet packet, listen_parameters param) and void render_graphics(...) and int main(). I created the text variables in main() and pass them as arguments to the thread that executes the function listen_to_server()

```
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include "player.h"


std::string PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST = "PLAYER_MOVE";
std::string CHIP_CREATION_REQUEST = "CHIP_CREATION";
std::string CHIP_DELETION_REQUEST = "CHIP_DELETION";
std::string MONSTER_ENTITY_MY = "monster";
std::string PLAYER_ENTITY_MY= "player";

    struct game_packet {
        std::string type;
        std::string player_move;
        double chip_position_x; // change it to string
        double chip_position_y;
        double pl1_position_x;
        double pl1_position_y;
        double pl2_position_x;
        double pl2_position_y;
        int score_pl1;
        int score_pl2;
    };

    struct listen_parameters {
        sf::TcpSocket* socket;
        player* player1;
        player* player2;
        sf::RenderWindow* what_window;
        std::list<player>* chipList;
        bool* lock_movement;
        sf::Text* pl1_score;
        sf::Text* pl2_score;
    };

    sf::Packet& operator <<(sf::Packet& packet, const game_packet& pack)
    {
        return packet << pack.type << pack.player_move << pack.chip_position_x << pack.chip_position_y
            << pack.pl1_position_x << pack.pl1_position_y << pack.pl2_position_x << pack.pl2_position_y
            << pack.score_pl1 << pack.score_pl2;
    }

    sf::Packet& operator >>(sf::Packet& packet, game_packet& pack)
    {
        return packet >> pack.type >> pack.player_move >> pack.chip_position_x >> pack.chip_position_y
            >> pack.pl1_position_x >> pack.pl1_position_y >> pack.pl2_position_x >> pack.pl2_position_y
            >> pack.score_pl1 >> pack.score_pl2;
    }

    void handle_plmove_request(game_packet packet, listen_parameters param) {
        std::stringstream int_to_string_pl1;
        std::stringstream int_to_string_pl2;
        double set_xpos = packet.pl1_position_x * 100 + 50;
        double set_ypos = packet.pl1_position_y * 100 + 50;
        param.player1->setCoordinates(set_xpos, set_ypos);
        set_xpos = packet.pl2_position_x * 100 + 50;
        set_ypos = packet.pl2_position_y * 100 + 50;
        param.player2->setCoordinates(set_xpos, set_ypos);
        int_to_string_pl1 << packet.score_pl1;
        param.pl1_score->setString(int_to_string_pl1.str());
        int_to_string_pl2 << packet.score_pl2;
        param.pl2_score->setString(int_to_string_pl2.str());
    }

    void handle_chip_deletion(game_packet packet, listen_parameters param) {
        std::cout << "handling chip_deletion_rquest" << std::endl;
        packet.chip_position_x = packet.chip_position_x * 100 + 50;
        packet.chip_position_y = packet.chip_position_y * 100 + 50;
        player chip_to_delete(packet.chip_position_x, packet.chip_position_y, MONSTER_ENTITY_MY, "0");
        std::cout << "deleting" << packet.chip_position_x << ","
                  << packet.chip_position_y;
        param.chipList->remove(chip_to_delete);
    }

    void handle_chip_creation(game_packet packet, listen_parameters param) {
        param.chipList->clear();
        std::string string_number;
        int new_integer;
        int xpos_newchip;
        int ypos_newchip;
        std::cout << "received integers" << std::endl;
        param.chipList->clear();
        for (auto& it : packet.player_move) {
            if (it != '_')
                string_number += it;
            else {
                std::stringstream string_to_int(string_number);
                string_to_int >> new_integer;
                std::cout << new_integer << ",";
                xpos_newchip = (new_integer % 8) * 100 + 50;
                ypos_newchip = (new_integer / 8) * 100 + 50;
                string_number.clear();
                player new_chip(xpos_newchip, ypos_newchip, MONSTER_ENTITY_MY , "0");
                param.chipList->push_back(new_chip);
            }

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }
    void listen_to_server(listen_parameters param){
        while (true) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            game_packet gamePacket;
            if (param.socket->receive(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                std::cout << "data couldn't be received" << std::endl;
            packet >> gamePacket;
            if (gamePacket.type == PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST)
                handle_plmove_request(gamePacket, param);
            else if (gamePacket.type == CHIP_DELETION_REQUEST) {
                handle_chip_deletion(gamePacket, param);
            }
            else if (gamePacket.type == CHIP_CREATION_REQUEST) {
                handle_chip_creation(gamePacket, param);
            }
        }
    }
    void render_graphics(listen_parameters param) {
        sf::Clock clock;
        sf::Clock bot_clock;
        sf::Font font;
        if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
            std::cout << "can't load" << std::endl;
        sf::Text player1_text;
        sf::Text player2_text;
        player1_text.setFont(font);
        player1_text.setString("PLAYER_1 SCORE");
        player1_text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        player1_text.setPosition(150, 850);
        player2_text.setFont(font);
        player2_text.setString("PLAYER_2 SCORE");
        player2_text.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        player2_text.setPosition(500, 850);

        sf::RectangleShape white_square(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
        white_square.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
        sf::RectangleShape black_square(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
        black_square.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
            while (param.what_window->isOpen()) {
                float two = 2;
                sf::Time elapsed1 = clock.getElapsedTime();
                sf::Time bot_elapsed = bot_clock.getElapsedTime();
                sf::Time two_seconds = sf::seconds(2);
                sf::Time one_millisecond = sf::milliseconds(10);

                if (elapsed1 > one_millisecond) {
                    bool isBlack = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 800; i += 100) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 800; j += 100) {
                            if (isBlack == true) {
                                black_square.setPosition(i + 50, j + 50);
                                param.what_window->draw(black_square);
                                if (j + 100 != 800)
                                    isBlack = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                white_square.setPosition(i + 50, j + 50);
                                param.what_window->draw(white_square);
                                if (j + 100 != 800)
                                    isBlack = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //std::cout << "displaying child thread" << std::endl;
                    param.player1->setShapePosition();
                    param.what_window->draw(param.player1->getPlayerShape());
                    param.player2->setShapePosition();
                    param.what_window->draw(param.player2->getPlayerShape());
                    param.what_window->draw(player1_text);
                    param.what_window->draw(player2_text);
                    param.what_window->draw(*(param.pl1_score)); // where the score is drawn
                    param.what_window->draw(*(param.pl2_score)); // where the score is drawn

                    for (auto& it : *(param.chipList)) {
                        it.setShapePosition();
                        param.what_window->draw(it.getPlayerShape());
                    }

                    param.what_window->display();
                    clock.restart();
                }
            }

    }

    int main()
    {
        int port_number = 53004;
        sf::TcpSocket socket;
        sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect("192.168.0.14", port_number);
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "awaiting connection" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "succesfull connection" << std::endl;
        sf::Packet packet;
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        std::string player_number;
        if (socket.receive(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
            std::cout << "can't receive packet" << std::endl;
        packet >> xpos >> ypos >> player_number;
        std::cout << "your player number is" << player_number << std::endl;
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(900, 1000), "SFML works!");
        window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
        window.setActive(false);


        player player1(50,750,PLAYER_ENTITY_MY, "1");
        player player2(750,750, PLAYER_ENTITY_MY, "2");
        sf::RenderWindow* ptr_window = &window;
        std::list<player> chipList;
        bool lock_movement = false;
        sf::Text pl1_score;
        sf::Text pl2_score;
        sf::Font font;
        if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
            std::cout << "can't load" << std::endl;
        pl1_score.setFont(font);
        pl1_score.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        pl1_score.setPosition(250, 950);
        pl2_score.setFont(font);
        pl2_score.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        pl2_score.setPosition(600, 950);
        pl1_score.setString("0");
        pl2_score.setString("0");

        listen_parameters param{&socket, &player1, &player2, ptr_window,&chipList,&lock_movement,
                                &pl1_score, &pl2_score};
        sf::Thread server_listener_thread{ &listen_to_server, param };
        server_listener_thread.launch();
        sf::Thread graphics(&render_graphics, param);
        graphics.launch();  


        while (window.isOpen()){
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                std::string ins;
                sf::Packet packet;
                if (lock_movement == false) {
                    switch (event.type)
                    {
                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                        window.close();
                        break;
                    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
                            game_packet gamePacket;
                            gamePacket.type = PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST;
                            ins = "r" + player_number;
                            gamePacket.player_move = ins;
                            packet << gamePacket;
                            if (socket.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "sending r instruction" << std::endl;
                        }
                        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
                            game_packet gamePacket;
                            gamePacket.type = PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST;
                            ins = "l" + player_number;
                            gamePacket.player_move = ins;
                            packet << gamePacket;
                            if (socket.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "sending l instruction" << std::endl;
                        }
                        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
                            game_packet gamePacket;
                            gamePacket.type = PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST;
                            ins = "u" + player_number;
                            gamePacket.player_move = ins;
                            packet << gamePacket;
                            if (socket.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "sending u instruction" << std::endl;
                        }
                        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
                            game_packet gamePacket;
                            gamePacket.type = PLAYER_MOVE_REQUEST;
                            ins = "d" + player_number;
                            gamePacket.player_move = ins;
                            packet << gamePacket;
                            if (socket.send(packet) != sf::Socket::Done)
                                std::cout << "couldn't send packet" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << "sending d instruction" << std::endl;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Summary: I am just updating text by changing it and redrawing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple: Just call `window.clear()` at the start of each main loop iteration. Right now you're never clearing the screen, just drawing over the previous one, which you won't notice as long as you fill everything. The problem is, you're never filling the area below the playing field, i.e. where the score is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, but now I can feel the lag between both clients. Before using the clear() function, both clients were synchronized perfectly.

Comment: @KingMetin2 Didn't check the networking part, but that shouldn't happen. You could also draw a black table behind the scores, but that's only hiding a potential issue.

Comment: @KingMetin2 `sf::Time one_millisecond = sf::milliseconds(10);` -- lies! More seriously, I don't see any sleeping in your code. Does SFML use VSYNC, or is the game just running as fast as possible? That might explain the difference in timing between two different machines.

Comment: Game updates every sf::Time one_millisecond. The way I am doing this is that when some of the clients makes a move, it first sends a request to the server and then the server sends a move request to all the clients including itself, so all the moves are synchronized across all the clients

Comment: I fixed it. The reason why I was getting such weird result is because I was putting the clear() function outside the if statement that tracks the time. I put it right before the for loop that creates the game board and it worked; however, I don't quiet understand why.